# How to do crucible/fisheye installation

Tags: atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

My organization has planned to got for fisheye and crucible and I am little confused after reading the documentation that crucible includes the installables for fisheye. I am confused whether should I install both seperately or only crucible.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to install them separately (this would defeat the purpose of their integration).  Install Crucible and then enter licenses for both products.